# Time format in laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel, time

I want to have an input, where you put a time in EU format like 12:00 or 21:34. (hh:mm)
How do I do that?

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('arena');
    $table->date("h,i"('beginn'));
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is what I have, but it's obviously wrong.

Comment: you can use $table->time('beginn');

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In laravel 5.6 you have this new feature that you can cast your timestamp so your migration should be like this

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('arena');
    $table->timestamp("begin");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And in your `Post` model you can simply do this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'begin' => 'date:hh:mm'
];
```

**Edit**
If you are NOT using laravel 5.6 you can use [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to easily manipulate data on setting on database or getting it from database so you can do something like this

```
public function getBeginAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('hh:mm');
}
```

And every time that you echoing it out in your blade or wherever like this `{{ $post->begin }}` it automatically changes the format for you.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `$table->time('field_name');`

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('title');
   $table->string('arena');
   $table->time("begin");
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: I tihnk it's time()  (singular)    https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with Carbon, which is included in Laravel by default:

1. Set a variable with the current time `$date = Carbon::now()`
2. Set hour, for example 22 `$date->hour = 22`
3. Set minutes, for example 54 `$date->minutes = 54`
4. Finally, set `$table->date($date)`

Answer (score 0):

Since laravel migration is based on traditional SQL convention, you cannot change the format using migration. This is because SQL datetime itself is formatted as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. But you can use Carbon date time format to show the stored date, time or both as per you wish.
Refer to this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon) for more on Carbon. [Official Link Here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)