# Laravel 5.8 migration : column type time (format hh:mm)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I have my project in Laravel 5.8.

This is my schema file:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->time('v_day1a')->default('00:00');
            $table->time('v_day1b')->default('00:00');
            $table->time('v_day2a')->default('00:00');
            $table->time('v_day2b')->default('00:00');
            $table->dateTime('last_activity')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

In database in v_day1a, v_day1b, v_day2a, v_day2b I have this format of time: 00:00:00. I need change this to 00:00 (hh:mm).

How can I make it?

Comment: yes, I have mysql :)

Comment: Never mind, I saw InnoDB afterwards :)

Comment: If it's a MySQL database then the format of type time columns is 'HH:MM:ss' so you can't set default to 00:00, just use as default 00:00:00. Also when you save later a time in this column use this format. To read later only the time without the seconds you can use `format('H:i')`.

Comment: In that case, how can I set the format HH: MM?

Comment: You should not try to change a database column to fit your output needs, instead you should insert data with as little loss of information as possible and use some code to format the output

Comment: In MySQL [the `TIME` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) has the 'hh:mm:ss' format (or 'hhh:mm:ss' for large hours), you can't just strip out the seconds, it's part of the type. But unlike @CodyKL suggested, you **can** set the value with the `HH:MM` format as MySQL will treat it as such. You can read the documentation I linked to understand how MySQL treats the TIME columns.

Comment: You shouldn't need to store it in a HH:MM format, you can just present it in that format when displaying it. Alternately you can just store it as a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time format in laravel migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925768/time-format-in-laravel-migration)